# Armor not showing on mannequins after I leave and return

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When i put armor on mannequins it shows. But when i leave the house and come back the armor does not show up on the mannequins. It still is in the inventory however. I already tried the [mannequins fix on the nexus](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10652/?). The fix makes things worse, now my mannequins <strike>disappear</strike> displace when putting new armor on them.

Comment: Do any of the fixes suggested for armor duplication on mannequins work for you? http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/64976326

Answer (score -3):

I would say it is the outfit issue.
Presumable they are set as normal actors and assigned as Outfit=none.
Every time you go away (so they would unload) they will revert to their basic outfit

or

Can be something about the very cell that made them unequip armor.
You can change the cell properties, under the "Interior Data" tab the "Encounter Zone"  set to "NoResetZone".

I have exactly the same problem. I got these information on other forums, I haven't tried it yet. I'll give you news

Comment: Welcome to the site; please check out the [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) for guidance on how Stack Exchange operates. Answers should contain expert advice; duplicating information from an other venue alone is not sufficient. If you've actually used the technique and confirm that it does work, that's a different matter -try first, then post.